# Druid metric shows more Good Response than Total Request in a particular time interval

Tags: pivot, sli, pydruid

I have an SLO whose SLI formula is Good Response ( responses which has 200 ohk in it) / Total request.

Somehow in a moment I am getting more amount of good events as compared to total events which is impossible. Cross validated the data and found out that the data flows perfectly fine and there is no duplication.

But When checked in druid(pivot) it shows at a time interval of 1 minute the response is little bit delayed and due to which in the next window the amount of good response we have one extra count making the total request to be less in the same window making my error budget more than 100% along with the target value of an SLO.

Is there any way to solve this ?

How can I set my window or do something so that I get the correct count in any window which I check.

So that my target value / error budget is not more than 100%